# How can i ask for payment on certificate download from user in wordpress's tutorLMS plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, lms

I'm looking to develop a platform where users can access courses for free. Upon completing a course, a 'Download Certificate' button will appear, requiring users to make a payment before they can download the certificate. How can I implement this feature on my website using tutorLMS plugin?

I am currently using TutorLMS to sell courses

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.